# Why can my Remote Desktop work one way, but not the other?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have 2 computers. Let's call the first one "CompA" (this is the desktop) and the second one "CompB" (this is the laptop). Both computers are on Windows 10 Pro.

Here is a list of settings made so far on both computers:

- System Properties > Remote

  - Set Radio Button to "Allow remote connections to this computer"
  - Unchecked the box for "Allow connections only from computers..."
- Windows Firewall > Inbound Rules

  - Remote Desktop - User Mode (UDP-In) is enabled
  - Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In) is enabled
  - Remote Desktop - Shadow (TCP-In) is enabled

On each computer, if I run the command "ping -a [IP of Other Comp]" it will return the name of the other computer, and proceed with "Request timed out" on all 4 sets of test data sent.

Within the same local network CompA can RDP into CompB via IP, but CompB can **not** RDP into CompA (via Comp Name or IP).

How do I get CompB to RDP into CompA?

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that you should double-check:

- Did you ensure that the network profile on CompA is not set to **Public**?  If so, you will need to change it to **Private**.
- You must authenticate with credentials for **an existing user profile on the remote host** (but it doesn't *need* to exist on the client that is attempting to connect).
- The authentication user profile used for remote sign-in **must have a password** set.
- The authentication user profile used for remote sign-in must be a member of either the **Administrators** group or the **Remote Desktop Users** group on the remote host.

[image: Windows 10 Remote Desktop]

[image: Windows 10 Remote Desktop Users]

([Source](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3982-rdc-connect-remotely-your-windows-10-pc.html))

Comment: My current settings match all 4 points to double check.

Comment: Quoting the comprehensive tutorial from that I referenced from TenForums.com, *"If using a simple username does not work and remote session cannot be created, try so called full username COMPUTER_NAME\USERNAME. For instance if the remote host is **MyMonsterMachine** and it has a user profile named **Number1Gamer**, use in remote sign in dialog username **MyMonsterMachine\Number1Gamer**."*

Comment: Taking it a step further, if the problem persists there must be something relatively obvious in the equation that we are missing.  When you _do_ try to connect, what are you seeing when it doesn't succeed?  Have we checked to ensure that there isn't some type of third-party firewall or security software that could be interfering?  Since `File and printer sharing` appears to be disabled on CompA based upon your ping test, have you tried to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case connecting using IP address instead of computer name solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can one up you. I'm using the same devices, the same remote login credentials, remoting to the same on premise computer. Both remote locations are on a standard spectrum internet package, using whatever standard spectrum provided cable box. One location (again using the same devices, a laptop and a desktop), the VPN and RDP connections work just fine, in the second location (same devices, same login, same everything minus the street address), the VPN connects but the RDP doesn't work. lol is all i can say to that and not spinning my wheels for a month trying to figure it out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).